# NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Tags: python

Я начал делать игру, где будут 9 кнопок и только 1 кнопка будет правильной. Правильные кнопки будут меняться и при нажатии неправильной кнопки счёт будет сбрасываться. В итоге при создании игры произошла(и) ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Game.py", line 25, in <module>
    tr = text(text=str(n)+'$', font=('Helvetica 100'))
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

```
from tkinter import *

clicks = 0
    
root = Tk()
root.title('Game')
root.geometry('720x1280')

def click_button():
    global clicks
    clicks = clicks + 1
    root.title("Clicks {}".format(clicks))
    label['text'] = str(n) + '$'

but_1 = Button(text='1', width=3, height=1, bg='blue', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_2 = Button(text='2', width=3, height=1, bg='green', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_3 = Button(text='3', width=3, height=1, bg='red', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_4 = Button(text='4', width=3, height=1, bg='yellow', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_5 = Button(text='5', width=3, height=1, bg='orange', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_6 = Button(text='6', width=3, height=1, bg='brown', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_7 = Button(text='7', width=3, height=1, bg='violet', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_8 = Button(text='8', width=3, height=1, bg='grey', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_9 = Button(text='9', width=3, height=1, bg='pink', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)

tr = text(text=str(n)+'$', font=('Helvetica 100'))
tr.pack()

but_1.place(x=210, y=240)
but_2.place(x=310, y=240)
but_3.place(x=410, y=240)
but_4.place(x=210, y=340)
but_5.place(x=310, y=340)
but_6.place(x=410, y=340)
but_7.place(x=210, y=440)
but_8.place(x=310, y=440)
but_9.place(x=410, y=440)

tr.place(x=100, y=110)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: функция `text` нигде не объявлена, вероятно, вы ожидали, что она появится благодаря `from tkinter import *`? Обратитесь к той странице, откуда вы брали этот пример использования. Еще лучше, обратитесь, пожалуйста, к документации на эту библиотеку. Подозреваю, что по аналогии с `Button`, надо было с большой буквы написать.

Comment: Класс текстового поля в tkinter - `Text`, с большой буквы.